# > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors BUILD FAILED (Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, build, android-manifest

Good day, Please help me understand and fix it

Plugin issue adobe.phonegap.push

When merging the manifest, I find out that it is necessary for some services to add: android:exported="true".
But after I added this and after building the service in the AndroidManifest.xml file are duplicated.

```
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest FAILED
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\recono\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:29:9-33:19 Error:
        Element service#com.adobe.phonegap.push.FCMService at AndroidManifest.xml:29:9-33:19 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:19:9-23:19
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\recono\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:34:9-38:19 Error:
        Element service#com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushInstanceIDListenerService at AndroidManifest.xml:34:9-38:19 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-28:19
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\recono\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        Validation failed, exiting
```

My config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <activity android:exported="true" />
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <service android:exported="true" />
    </edit-config>
</platform>


<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" spec="2.3.0">
    <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="656893750954" />
</plugin>
<platform name="android">
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
</platform>
```

My AndroidMainfes.xml  after trying to build

```
<application android:exported="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <meta-data android:name="launchnavigator.GOOGLE_API_KEY" android:value="" />
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushHandlerActivity" android:permission="${applicationId}.permission.PushHandlerActivity" />
        <receiver android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.BackgroundActionButtonHandler" />
        <receiver android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushDismissedHandler" />
        <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.FCMService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushInstanceIDListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.FCMService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushInstanceIDListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
```